# What's a good subterranean vegetation - other than bio-luminescent fungi?

Tags: biology, flora

So, I've made... a lot of subterranean worlds. It's a favorite of mine. And, every single time, the major form of vegetation and light was blue, glowing mushrooms, and glowing crystals. While I think light sources are no struggle, I've had issues avoiding the ever-present trope of glowing blue mushrooms, lichens, mosses, etc. Definitely vibrant, preferably edible and/or useful for tools and buildings, but not necessary.

So, **what vibrant vegetation would fit thematically aside from them?**

Comment: actually you could realistically have a forest underground if say there was a really large crystal that acts like a sun. I think our present flora is quite vibrant already but you could make them maybe have crystal like leaves or whatever you want them to have

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Mold

Molds are a classic thing that grow underground. According to [this site](https://web.extension.illinois.edu/healthyair/mold.cfm)

> Molds need moisture that can come from water leaks, flooding, high relative humidity, or condensation. And, molds require oxygen, but not light. Without the proper conditions, molds may not grow but become dormant. Then when conditions are again right for growth, they begin to regenerate.

---

### Oozes

Oozes also don't need light to grow. (they're one of the quintessential D&D monsters). Examples are slimes, gelatinous cubes, and the ooze itself.

---

### Fungi

So too are fungi (mushrooms). Believe it or not there are vast networks of mushrooms underground that support life above the surface in the jungles. Without this under footing of mushrooms, many plants wouldn't be able to survive!

---

### Moss, Ferns, etc.

According to [this site](http://www.caveslime.org/kids/cavejourney/caveJourneyWhatPlants.html), while not adapting to the dark per se, mosses, ferns and/or liverworts may be in the twilight zone, which are low-light areas where light decreases from the full intensity of the surface. Such organisms are adapted to the very low light regions where the twilight zone meets the darker areas of the cave and like the constantly cool, moist environment provided by the cave entrance.

---

### Roots

Roots can grow into the cave. Even though they aren't a separate entity that exists from the plant above the surface, they are still something that grows into caves. Keep in mind that root structures weaken caves, and if there's sufficient weight above the surface, it'll cause it to collapse into the caves below.

Comment: Mold *is* fungi.  And ooses are not classified as fungi would not be “vegitation” at all.

Comment: @JDługosz Well, due to the existence of slime molds, I'd say oozes can, to some extent, be classified as plants/fungi.

Comment: I should probably edit the OP to reflect this, (though ferns would fit to an extent,) I had meant _vibrant_ vegetation. Many molds, roots, and such are dull grey/brown/beige/greinge in color.

I do wonder if Wikipedia has a "List of subterranian organisms" category.

Comment: @JDługosz I'm looking at WB from a tabletop RPG standpoint. Even though they're a separate category in games, there are quite a few things IRL and in games that blur the lines

Comment: @Papayaman1000 do you mean 'vibrant' or 'green'?

Comment: @JohnFeltz Either or. Primarily, eye-catching, or just generally a sharp contrast against the dull, dark, dirty colors of a cave system.

Comment: @Papayaman1000 if you weren't looking for biological structures, crystals fit the bill! But they're not alive...

Comment: @Papayaman1000 I think you might be suffering from a false equivalency.  The reason the classical fantasy mushrooms, etc. look dull is because the light is low (or magical), and we'd be using more B&W vision rather than color vision.  There are plenty of fungi that (in normal daylight) are bright orange, or white with red spots, etc.  Even bread mold is blue/green.

Comment: @JesseCohoon I'm primarily trying to generally _avert_ the trope of fungi, moss, lichens, crystals, etc., not trying to verify those things existing.

It's mostly for just creating the setting in general, the D&D campaign is just an event in the setting.

Comment: @Papayaman1000 you might want to try researching on tvtropes.org - there's lots of examples of how to avert tropes, and you can use their ideas as a springboard.

Comment: @JesseCohoon Research on TV Tropes? You just recommend that so nonchalantly with no regards to my free time...

Seriously, I spend a good couple hours a day on that site though :P

Comment: @Papayaman1000 I am a DM, player, and game designer. I've used that source to the utmost. If you hadn't stumbled across it, I thought I'd mention it. But you're right it IS a black hole!

Comment: @Papayaman1000 given enough light *anything* can grow underground. If you could amp up the bio-luminescence to sunlight (or even dusk, or false dawn) like levels, a good variety of things might be able to grow

Comment: @JesseCohoon Good point. I had sort of wanted to avoid just miscellaneous surface vegetation, or some underground jungle, but 'tis not an original idea under the sun. Come to think of it, I've wasted away the past month playing Fallen London; maybe I could take cues from there ("Fallen" referring to its physical location, not in the 'given in to attack' sense used in the similarly-named film(s)). Seriously worth checking out, it's a free interactive story over [here.](http://fallenlondon.storynexus.com/Gap/Load?content=%2fStorylet%2fAvailable#)
Addendum: Perhaps we should move this to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44461/discussion-between-jesse-cohoon-and-papayaman1000).

Comment: @Papayaman1000 plants and fungi are different things. Saying «plants/fungi» as a category doesn’t match modern classifications, as fungi are more closely related to animals than they are to plants, so you pretty much pull in the entirety of the main eucaryote liniage.  The *name* “slime mold” is outdated, as noted in the intro of the Wikipedia article.